# Axios response not triggered and Node execution silently stops

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

I make an HTTP call with Axios meant to respond with 200 (tested on Postman).
But the response is not triggered in try/catch/finally logic and the execution weirdly stops.

The code looks like this:

```js
(async () => {
  const axios = require('axios');

  const url = ''; // The URL responds with a HTML page
  const cookies = ''; // The cookies are checked with Postman
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Cookie: cookies
    }
  };

  try {
    let res = await axios.get(url, config);

    console.log('Response received.');
    console.log(res);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('Error happened.');
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    console.log('Finally block.');
  }

  console.log('End of execution.');
})()
```

All `console.log` aren't called. I even tried to put `debugger` or other actions not related to writing on stdout but they aren't called either.

The status returned by the process is `0`.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, `await` should use in `async` function

Comment: Yes, it is actually. It's wrapped in a closure. I'll update the question.

Comment: This seems to work fine, is that all there is and is it exactly what you have?

Comment: Yes, this code is exactly the one I use (with the URL and the cookies set obviously). And when I use a debugger, I see the execution suddenly stops after the Axios call, this is very weird...

Comment: This works fine on my end, do you see anything if you do `(async () => {...})().catch(console.error)` printed in the `console`?

Comment: I just tested and it doesn't print anything. I also tested with calling a sample URL such as `https://google.com` and it works, so the error should be caused by the response of the URL I'm trying to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution, my program was stopping because my request wasn't resolved.

I needed to set the `connection` header to `keep-alive`, and now it works properly.